# build failed while run ant file

Tags: java, ant, build, myeclipse, apache-torque

I'm trying to run ant `build.xml` but some error occur

```
Buildfile: D:\Projects\OBSWorkspace\schoolforms\torque\build.xml
main:

BUILD FAILED
D:\Projects\OBSWorkspace\schoolforms\torque\build.xml:19: 
   The following error occurred while executing this line:
   D:\Projects\OBSWorkspace\schoolforms\torque\build-torque.xml:52:     
   D:\Projects\OBSWorkspace\schoolforms\torque\${torque.home}\lib not found.
```

in this project `${torque.home}` not found which directory it is indicated that

```
  Assume torque.home is specified through -D option
  in ant invocation
```

What does -D specified, how to find `${torque.home}` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it in this way `ant build -Dtorque.home="value for torque.home"`. Using `-D` param you can pass property from command line directly to build. If you pass value from command line to build it will be visible in all your builds even if you pass `invokeAll=false`.

I think that [here](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/passing-paramter-to-eclipse-arguments-td4539212.html) is the answer how to pass parameters from eclipse to ant (`Eclipse->myproject->right click on build.xml->Arguments->VM Arguments 
-DappRoot=ECM -DappName=ESW -Dapp.module=FNT -Dapp.env=LOC -DcloneNumber=1`)

Comment: but in myeclipse how to pass -D option parameter